# Symfony 4.4 FormType problem with validate

Tags: forms, symfony, validation, symfony4, form-submit

I have a problem with my validation form when I submit there is no error message just refresh the page and I don't understand what I have forget? I tried with SubmitType but I have the same problem.

My FormType

```
class FilmType extends AbstractType
{
   public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
   {

    $builder
        ->add('titre')
        ->add('resume')
        ->add('dateSortie')
        ->add('personnages', EntityType::class, [
            'class' => Personnage::class,
            'query_builder' => function (PersonnageRepository $pr) {
                return $pr->createQueryBuilder('p')
                    ->orderBy('p.nom', 'ASC');
            },
            'choice_label' => 'nom'
        ])
        ->getForm();
}

public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults([
        'data_class' => Film::class,
    ]);
}
```

}

My Controller, I think is ok

```
 /**
 *
 * @param Request $request
 * @Route("/film/new", name="film_new")
 * @return Response
 *
 */
public function new(Request $request): Response
{
    $film = new Film();
    $form = $this->createForm(FilmType::class, $film);
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
        $entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $entityManager->persist($film);
        $entityManager->flush();

        return $this->redirectToRoute('home');
    }

    return $this->render('film/new.html.twig', [
        'film' => $film,
        'form' => $form->createView(),
    ]);
}
```

MY Twig, I add form_errors but nothing more

```
{% block body %}
    <form>
        <div class="form-group">
            {{ form_start(form)}}
            {{ form_errors(form) }}
            {{ form_widget(form) }}
            <button> Envoyer </button>
            {{ form_end(form) }}
        </div>
    </form>
{% endblock %}
```

My Film entity.....

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\FilmRepository")
 */
class Film
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $titre;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="text")
     */
    private $resume;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="date")
     */
    private $dateSortie;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Personnage", mappedBy="film")
     */
    private $personnages;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->personnages = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getTitre(): ?string
    {
        return $this->titre;
    }

    public function setTitre(string $titre): self
    {
        $this->titre = $titre;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getResume(): ?string
    {
        return $this->resume;
    }

    public function setResume(string $resume): self
    {
        $this->resume = $resume;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getDateSortie(): ?\DateTimeInterface
    {
        return $this->dateSortie;
    }

    public function setDateSortie(\DateTimeInterface $dateSortie): self
    {
        $this->dateSortie = $dateSortie;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection|Personnage[]
     */
    public function getPersonnages(): Collection
    {
        return $this->personnages;
    }

    public function addPersonnage(Personnage $personnage): self
    {
        if (!$this->personnages->contains($personnage)) {
            $this->personnages[] = $personnage;
            $personnage->addFilm($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removePersonnage(Personnage $personnage): self
    {
        if ($this->personnages->contains($personnage)) {
            $this->personnages->removeElement($personnage);
            $personnage->removeFilm($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }
```

Comment: Did you just want to display errors ? Or your form doesn't submit ?

Comment: My form doesn' submit ! It only refresh my template,  so I want display error to understand what is the problem, but the form_errors display nothing here

Comment: Nothing in the Profiler bar ?

Comment: I edit my post to show you my profiler

Comment: Thx, bothing here, please add var_dump($request->request);die; just after your  if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) { and show us the result

Comment: There is no result , its like the execution no enter in the if isSubmitted, maybe a problem with the button ?

Comment: Without the isValid() ?? You ran your project with symfony server ? Or something else ? If you want I can download your project and correct it, try to.....

Comment: Did you use "make:crud Film" to make this form/controller ?

Comment: I tried with/whitin isValid actually with isValid, I run with bin/console server:start 
I did make:form and make Controller sepparately

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit your FilmType.php to:

Add `'multiple' => true` to get an Array of Personnages[] :)

```
<?php

namespace App\Form;

use App\Entity\Film;
use App\Entity\Personnage;
use App\Repository\PersonnageRepository;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Form\Type\EntityType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;

class FilmType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('titre')
            ->add('resume')
            ->add('dateSortie')
            ->add('personnages', EntityType::class, [
                'class' => Personnage::class,
                'query_builder' => function (PersonnageRepository $pr) {
                    return $pr->createQueryBuilder('p')
                        ->orderBy('p.nom', 'ASC');
                },
                'choice_label' => 'nom',
                'multiple' => true
            ])

                    ->getForm();

    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => Film::class,
        ]);
    }
}
```

Don't forget to acccept if it's working for you :)

Comment: Add Type to my form changed nothing but i tried to clone my project and run make:crud and its works and its the same code , crazy !! But without personnages, when I include personnages I have this error :

Could not determine access type for property "personnages" in class "App\Entity\Film": The property "personnages" in class "App\Entity\Film" can be defined with the methods "addPersonnage()", "removePersonnage()" but the new value must be an array or an instance of \Traversable, "App\Entity\Personnage" given..

Comment: If It's not working share me your code or host it in dev and share url.

Comment: I edited my answer too :) but when i paste a we transfert url it doesn't works

Comment: there is my url project just add the space ;) https: // we. tl/t-psOapJ4zA8

Comment: Ok, I will check that !

Comment: It's working in your project with this EDITED answer code :)

Comment: https ://projects.bzez .dev/filmo/filmotheque.zip

Comment: Remove spaces ^^ I just change the FormType, make change and have fun :) Don't forget to accept answer dude.

Answer (score 0):

Change your controller:

```
 /**
 *
 * @param Request $request
 * @Route("/film/new", name="film_new")
 * @return Response
 *
 */
public function new(Request $request): Response
{
    $film = new Film();
    $form = $this->createForm(FilmType::class, $film);
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
        $entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $entityManager->persist($film);
        $entityManager->flush();

        $this->addFlash('success', 'SUCCESS!');
        return $this->redirectToRoute('home');
    }

    return $this->render('film/new.html.twig', [
        'film' => $film,
        'form' => $form->createView(),
    ]);
}
```

And change your twig template:

```
{% block body %}
    {% for message in app.flashes('success') %}
        <div>
            {{ message }}
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
    <hr>
    <form>
        <div class="form-group">
            {{ form_start(form)}}
            {{ form_errors(form) }}
            {{ form_widget(form) }}
            <button> Envoyer </button>
            {{ form_end(form) }}
        </div>
    </form>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: I trie to add this line but i don't have a message error

Comment: Remove the && $form->isValid() and try again plz.

Comment: @Michel Clear cache and try again

Comment: I removed $form->isValid and Clear Cach and nothing changed... I did exactly like the symfony doc grrr!

Comment: I implement your code but the execution don't enter in if isSubmitted

Comment: @Michel you add '&& $form->isValid()' or no?

Comment: Yes I tried with and whithout and Its the same thing, but I Have Clone my project and do make:crud and it works but I have an error I write about it on the bZezzz Post :)

Comment: Check my answer.